# pycharm не узнает метод append

Tags: python

Выдает ошибку:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

Почему так? И как это исправить?

```py
from random import randint
numb = []
for r in range(5):
    n = randint(-50, 35)
    numb = numb.append(n)
    print(numb)
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас ошибка такова: без ошибок выполняется первая итерация, но, на строке 5, вы совершили грубейшую ошибку, со всеми бывает, для добавления нового элемента в массив, вам надо просто написать `numb.append(n)`, а у вас происходит присваивание результата функции `append`, к переменной `numb`, следовательно, в следующей итерации у вас будет не массив, а результат функции `append`, из предыдущей итерации. проще говоря вам надо исправить ваш код на это:

```
from random import randint
numb = []
for r in range(5):
    n = randint(-50, 35)
    numb.append(n)
    print(numb)
```